# Is there an implementation of VAR-EGARCH model in R or Stata?

Tags: time-series, programming, garch, econometrics

I am writing my undergrad honor thesis and want to run a multivariable VAR-EGARCH model.

Is there any package in R or formulas in Stata 14 that allows me to implement directly?

If not, could you give me some advice?

Comment: Please provide a link to a definition for VAR-EGARCH model or even better, add it in the body of the question. For the package, just googling give a lot of potential candidates, have you tried some of these? Is the implementation for this particular version missing?

Comment: Thanks for your advice! The model I am looking for is " first order of Vector autoregression" combine "first order of Exponential Generalized Autoregressive Conditional Heteroskedasticity". I notice that there is a package named "rmgarch" and "rugarch" but they cannot solve my problem.

Comment: For example:  I am looking for a model that first contain: x_t = A0+A1*x_{t-1} + Error(VAR(1,1); then(Error)=  (Variance-Co-variance matrix)^(1/2)*(a white noise process); ultimately, log (Variance-co-variance matrix ) =κ+γ1logσ2t−1+α1[εt−1σt−1−E{εt−1σt−1}]+ξ1(εt−1σt−1) (EGARCH(1,1))  [Link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/specify-egarch-models-using-egarch.html)(http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/vartovec.html)

Comment: Could you please edit your question by adding your comment in it so that it is clear and readable for the community? Then somebody might be able to answer it.

Comment: Thank you! I am kind of new in this forum! I will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RATS software in which VAR GARCH is inbuilt function with CCC, DCC VECH and BEKK for co-variance estimation.

Answer (score 0):

If for VAR-EGARCH you mean a BEKK model the `MTS`package in R can implement a BEKK(1,1)